# Rapidshare and Megaupload traffic shaping by ISP

Tags: networking, traffic-shaping

I think my ISP is shaping Rapidshare and Mega Upload traffic, the download speed goes down to 30 kb/s every time and only on those sites, I've tried with different programs for downloading and the same happens, is there anyway I could prove they are shaping the traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the free versions of these sites? If so, it's possible that the sites themselves are  limiting your download bandwidth if you are downloading lots of of data (in order to increase sales of premium accounts). There is a Rapidshare "[accelerator](http://themoviefind.com/rapidshare/)" which automates the tedious process of downloading multiple files from Rapidshare, so it's not surprising that Rapidshare would find other ways to persuade users to pay for the premium service.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test if your ISP shape your bandwidth when you download at rapidshare or megaupoad. Try to put Sock on your download manager and see if there's difference ;)